# import com.microsoft.windowsazure.messaging.*; is not detected. Which library should i add in android studio?

Tags: android, azure, azure-notificationhub, azure-mobile-services

I am using azure notification hub in my android app.
after following all procedures i am getting an error.

```
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.messaging.*;
```

is not detected.
and  `private NotificationHub hub;` is not getting declared

Am i missing some library?

Comment: i solved the problem ..i was missing the "notification-hubs0.4" jar. so now "import com.microsoft.windowsazure.messaging.*;
" shows no error. But "NotificationHub" class is still not detected, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The NotificationHub class is in com.microsoft.windowsazure.messaging.notificationhubs.*